How to extend a class if declared this way
For a certain reason, I have to declare my classes this way:
const core = {
    character: class {
        constructor(arg) {}
    }
}

Works pretty, but I don't know how to extends the class 'character'. I'm trying the way below, but it doesn't work:
const core = {
  character: class {
    constructor(arg) {}
  },
  enemy: class extends core.character {
    constructor(arg) {}
  }
}


See: Self-references in object literals / initializers

"For a certain reason, I have to declare my classes this way" - please expand on that reason. What is the constraint exactly?

You are trying to use core inside its own initialization, which is not allowed in JavaScript. To fix it, you can initialize the extended classes after the base class:


const core = {
  character: class {
    isCharacter = true;
    constructor(arg) {}
  }
};
core.enemy = class extends core.character {
  isEnemy = true;
  constructor(arg) {
    super();
  }
};

console.log(new core.enemy());




Wow! Can't believe I didn't thought that. Thank you very much!

For the record: it's a bit more work, but you can do things without class syntax (using composition).


const character1 = createCharacter(`hostile`);
const character2 = createCharacter(`friendly`);
const character3 = createCharacter();

console.log(`character1 =>`, character1);
console.log(`character2 =>`, character2);
console.log(`character3 =>`, character3);

character2.character = `whodunnit`; // frozen, no can do
console.log(`is character1 the enemy? ${character1.isEnemy}`);
console.log(`is character2 the enemy? ${character2.isEnemy}`);
console.log(`is character3 the enemy? ${character3.isEnemy}`);

// ---
function characterConstructor(chr) {
  return Object.freeze({
    character: chr ?? ``,
    isCharacter: chr?.length > 0,
  });
}

function createCharacter(character) {
  const core = clone(characterConstructor(character));
  Object.defineProperty( core, `isEnemy`, {
    get() {
      return !core.isCharacter ? `UNKNOWN` 
        : core.character === `hostile` ? `YES` : `NO`; 
    }, 
    enumerable: true, } );
  
  return Object.freeze(core);
}

function clone(obj) {
  return Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj ?? {}))
    .reduce((clone, [key, value]) => 
      Object.defineProperty(clone, key, value), {});
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}



